# TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

```
plt.plot(train_accuracy, label='training accuracy')
plt.plot(test_accuracy, label='validation accuracy')
plt.title('Accuracy at the end of each epoch')
plt.legend();
```

> Error:
>
> TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use
> Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
>
> for eg, test_accuracy is  [tensor(0.6943, device='cuda:0',
> dtype=torch.float64),  tensor(0.6891, device='cuda:0',
> dtype=torch.float64),  tensor(0.7409, device='cuda:0',
> dtype=torch.float64),  tensor(0.7202, device='cuda:0',
> dtype=torch.float64),  tensor(0.7565, device='cuda:0',
> dtype=torch.float64),  tensor(0.6891, device='cuda:0',
> dtype=torch.float64),  tensor(0.7047, device='cuda:0',
> dtype=torch.float64),  tensor(0.7409, device='cuda:0',
> dtype=torch.float64),  tensor(0.6943, device='cuda:0',
> dtype=torch.float64)]

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, you need to copy the tensor to host memory first.

Try:

```
train_accuracy = [x.cpu().numpy() for x in train_accuracy]

test_accuracy = [x.cpu().numpy() for x in test_accuracy]

plt.plot(train_accuracy, label='training accuracy')
plt.plot(test_accuracy, label='validation accuracy')
plt.title('Accuracy at the end of each epoch')
plt.legend();
```

Comment: After trying this, I got another error saying AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'cpu'

Comment: please see the edit and let me know

Comment: I will definitely try this, but this also worked for me : torch.tensor(test_accuracy).detach().cpu().numpy()  and then did the plotting part